# Is it possible to define a `function` and insert it in `formula` to construct a `model.frame` in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I was trying to extract a `model.frame` in R by defining a function to use it in formula as:

```
library(Formula)
df <- data.frame(c = LETTERS[1:2], a = c(74, 80), b = c(8, 10))
soln <- function(x, y){
     A <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, -2), nrow=2)
     B <- matrix(c(x, y), nrow=2)
     return((as.matrix(solve(A)%*%B))[1,])
}
F1 <- Formula::Formula(c ~ . | (soln(a, b)))
mf <- stats::model.frame(F1, data = df)
mf
  c  a  b  soln(a, b)
1 A 74  8  76.000000
2 B 80 10   8.666667
```

Here `mf` provides a `data.frame` that does NOT match the actual value from `soln()` function. In fact `soln(74, 8) = 52` and `soln(80, 10) = 56.66667`, but in `mf` it is showing `76` and `8.666667`. How is this function working in the model formula? Is it possible to define a function to get the correct values in the `model.frame` this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the sequence of rows to get the expected output

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) model.frame(F1, data = df[i,])))
#  c  a  b soln(a, b)
#1 A 74  8   52.00000
#2 B 80 10   56.66667
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_split(rn = row_number()) %>%
   map_df(~ model.frame(F1, data = .x))
#  c  a  b rn soln(a, b)
#1 A 74  8  1   52.00000
#2 B 80 10  2   56.66667
```